# Display same document in different xpage in different tab

Tags: xpages

My need is hopefully simple.  I am looking at a document on the web in document.xps.  I created a second xpage (printer friendly version) named documentPrint.xps.  I want to open document in documentPrint.xps from document.xps in a new via a button named "Print Fritndly".  I am able to open it in same tab via a button using SSJS.  Current SSJS button code:

```
    var path = sessionScope.host + sessionScope.dbPath + "/" +    viewScope.printPage + "?" + viewScope.queryString;
    context.redirectToPage(path);
```

I searched this and other sites for days and only seem to find answers that open the document from a view link not a button.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: I meant to say open document in new tab, not the same tab, which I am already able to do with code posted.

Answer (score 0):

I knew it was simple.  CSJS in button:

```
    var host = window.location.href;
    var url = host.replace("Document", "DocumentPrint");
    window.open(url,"_blank");
```

So an address like this:
http://abc.comwebsite.nsf/Document.xsp?documentId=2DF75E4B505A2D5F88257FB20050D2E0&action=openDocument

becomes:
http://abc.comwebsite.nsf/DocumentPrint.xsp?documentId=2DF75E4B505A2D5F88257FB20050D2E0&action=openDocument